# error handling when opening either file or stdin

Tags: c, file, error-handling, getline

My program reads from file if filename was provided, and from `stdin` otherwise:

```
if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
    if ( !(f = fopen(argv[1], "r")) )
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
}
else
    f = stdin;

while ((size = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
...
```

Is this correct error handling?
Do I need error handling for `stdin`, or is there no scenario where the open will fail?

As an aside, I am slightly confused that `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` returns true where it literally "is **NOT** a TTY".

I would have expected my if check to work reversely.

Comment: Your code does not do what you describe – to check "if a filename was provided", you'd check `argc > 1`, but instead you are checking whether `STDIN_FILENO` is a terminal type device. `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` should indeed return `1` if stdin (fileno #0) is a terminal type device (as opposed to, say, input from a pipe or redirected from a file e.g. `< /tmp/foobar`)

Comment: Deciding whether or not to read from a file or from `stdin` based on `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` isn't going to work well.  What happens if such a process is started by another process that had its `stdin` redirected from `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is

```c
FILE *f;
if ( argc < 2 || strcmp( argv[1], "-" ) == 0 ) {
   f = stdin;
} else {
   f = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
   if ( !f ) {
      perror(argv[1]);
      exit( 1 );
   }
}
```

Explanation follows.

---

You're over-complicating things. You only need to look at the arguments.

- `./prog` should read from `stdin`.
- `./prog -` should read from `stdin`. (Optional)
- `./prog file` should read from file `file`.

If so,

- `./prog file` works as intended.
- `./prog <file` works as intended.
- `cat file | ./prog` works as intended.

This is a common paradigm.

```
$ echo 'From file' >file

$ echo 'From stdin' | cat
From stdin
$ echo 'From stdin' | cat -
From stdin
$ echo 'From stdin' | cat file
From file

$ echo 'From stdin' | grep ''
From stdin
$ echo 'From stdin' | grep '' -
From stdin
$ echo 'From stdin' | grep '' file
From file

$ echo 'From stdin' | perl -pe1
From stdin
$ echo 'From stdin' | perl -pe1 -
From stdin
$ echo 'From stdin' | perl -pe1 file
From file

$ echo 'echo "From file"' >file

$ echo 'echo "From stdin"' | sh
From stdin
$ echo 'echo "From stdin"' | sh -
From stdin
$ echo 'echo "From stdin"' | sh file
From file
```

Deciding to read from stdin or not based on whether it's a terminal could result in problems. It's quite common for stdin to be something other than a terminal. For example, the stdin of daemons aren't connected to a terminal, and thus the stdin of program launched by deamons aren't terminals (unless the daemon takes steps to make it so).

`isatty` should only be used here if you want to refuse to read from a terminal. I've seen a program or two do that, but it's extremely rare.

---

> I am slightly confused that isatty(STDIN_FILENO) returns true where it literally "is NOT a TTY".

You are confused indeed. It does the opposite. "isatty() returns 1 if fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal; otherwise 0 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the error."

Answer (score 2):

> My program reads from file if filename was provided, and from `stdin` otherwise

You should just test if a filename was provided and use `fopen()` to open the file or assign `stdin` to the `FILE *f` otherwise.

After you are done reading from `f`, you can also compare `f == stdin` to determine whether to close the file or keep `stdin` open.

`isatty()` is used to test if the standard input is attached to a terminal, `STDIN_FILENO` being the system handle for the standard input, `0` on unix systems. This function is not part of the C Standard but defined in the POSIX Standard.

`isatty(fd)` returns non zero if the system handle `fd` refers to a terminal. It will return `0` if `fd` is invalid (and `errno` is set to `EBADF`) and also if `fd` does not refer to a terminal, setting `errno` to `EINVAL` or `ENOTTY` (as specified by POSIX.1-2001).

As coded, the program tests if standard input has been redirected from a file or a pipe, in which case it reads from `stdin`, otherwise (if `stdin` is attached to a terminal) it attempts to open the filename.  `fopen` can fail of course, and if no filename was provided, passing a null pointer to `fopen` will actually cause undefined behavior.  Just testing if the filename was provided seems more appropriate.

It is customary in many unix tools to read from `stdin` if no filename is provided or if the filename is `"-"`, so you might want to support this convention as well.

Also note that `getline` takes a pointer to the buffer allocated size and returns the length of the line read from the stream.  Thus it seems more consistent to transpose the variable names.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *f;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-")) {
        // use standard input
        f = stdin;
    } else {
        // try and open the first command line argument
        if ((f = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
            perror(argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    ssize_t len;
    while ((len = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
        ...
    }
    free(line);
    if (f != stdin) {
        fclose(f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you. You have a typo `arg < 2` should be `argc < 2`.