# ENOTTY: Inappropriate ioctl for device: program works, but not when executed inside <()

Tags: c, tty, ioctl, strace

I have simple program that reads file line by line, and prints each line. The core of the program is:

```
while ((size = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1)
    printf("%s", line);
```

Now I have following problem:

this works:

```
./test zz
```

this also works:

```
/bin/cat <(./test zz)
```

but when I pipe the output to other program, it does not work:

```
/bin/cat <(./test zz) | /bin/cat
```

there is no output.
When I compare with `strace` the one that works, and the one that doesn't:

```
/bin/cat <(strace ./test zz)

/bin/cat <(strace ./test zz) | /bin/cat
```

I see this error: `-1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)`

```
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7ffc302104d0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55b4e1fd3000
brk(0x55b4e1ff4000)                     = 0x55b4e1ff4000
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(0x1, 0x3), ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7ffc30210350)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
read(0, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(0)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

## EDIT:

here is my proof-of-concept code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *f;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t size, cut;


    if (!isatty(STDIN_FILENO) || argc < 2 || (argv[1] == "-"))
        f = stdin;
    else
        if (!(f = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
            perror(argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }

    while ((size = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1)
    printf("%s", line);

    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(f);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

## EDIT2:

I have removed the part: `(!isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` and that fixed the problem. But I don't understand what is happening.

I originally added this, so that my program can take filename as argument `./test zz` or take input from pipe `cat zz | ./test`.

Comment: works for me - with fgets instead of your getLine

Comment: The `ioctl` is the implementation of the `isatty` function, which either your code or the standard library presumably calls.  The "error" return simply indicates that fd 0 is not a terminal, which is correct.  So I don't think that's directly related to your problem.  You should post a [mcve].

Comment: @Nate Eldredge thanks. I have added proof-of-concept code. Please see my edit.

Comment: Why are you doing this? `!isatty(STDIN_FILENO)`

Comment: If you want each line to be written out to the pipe as soon as you print it, then you have to fflush immediately - i.e. *inside* the loop, not after it completes.  Your program does work as it stands, in that all the input eventually gets echoed to the output - just not immediately after every line.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge - I moved the flush inside the while loop, but it makes no difference.

Comment: @Solomon Ucko - please see my second edit

Comment: Aside: `argv[1] == "-"` does not do what you want. Use `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: It seems that standard input of the `./test` execution is not actually coming from a terminal. Are you running it from an IDE?

Comment: @Ian Abbott - no. I am in the terminal.

Comment: I guess it must be something to do with the shell then.

Comment: Just to confirm, does `[ -t 0 ] && echo terminal` output `terminal`?

Comment: @Ian Abbott - yes. all teh above was done in `zsh` and when I do as you say it returns `terminal`. But interestingly, when I use bash, instead of `zsh` the command works fine: `/bin/cat <(./test zz) | /bin/cat`

Comment: @Ian Abbott - could you please explain why I should use `strcmp` instead of`argv[1] == "-"`? It seems to work fine.

Comment: @400theCat, because the version with `==` doesn't mean what you think it means. See [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8004237/2402272)

Comment: OK, so it seems to something to do with the way Zsh supplies standard input for that command. I don't know why it would supply standard input for `./test` differently in `/bin/cat <(./test)` and `/bin/cat <(./test) | /bin/cat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any of the following conditions are true, the program uses stdin for input:

- stdin isn't connected a terminal.
- No arguments were provided.
- The first argument is `-`.

In the scenario you presented, stdin isn't connected to a terminal<sup>[1]</sup>, so the `test` reads from stdin. You don't get the desired result since you want to read from the file `zz`.

The first condition (`!isatty(STDIN_FILENO)`) makes no sense. You were correct to remove it. The remaining two conditions are sufficient to make `cat zz | ./test` work.

---

1. I don't know why. But it's not important. There are plenty of times stdin isn't a terminal. For example, the stdin of daemons aren't terminals, and thus the stdin of program launched by deamons aren't terminals unless the daemon takes steps to make it so.

Comment: this solutiuon was suggested to me when I asked few days ago:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75730197/error-handling-when-opening-either-file-or-stdin how else should I decide whether my program is on the receiving side of a pipe?

Comment: But you don't need to know whether it's on the receiving end of a pipe.

Answer (score -3):

The flush should be done to stdout, not the file you're reading.

Comment: fixed that. But it makes no difference.